# SQLite does not like inner joins?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am having trouble with `sqlite` in an `android` application. 
It seems that any JOIN OPERATION totally kills my performance

One table is a fts3 table because my application is a dictionary and I read fts3 benefits dictionary like look ups.
These are my 2 tables I want to join (mainly getting the meaning of the word (okurigana) in different languages :

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE tango USING fts3 (okurigana, kana, pos, pos_detail);
CREATE TABLE translation (_id int(7), language VARCHAR(10), meaning VARCHAR(100), FOREIGN KEY (_id) REFERENCES tango(rowid));
CREATE INDEX lang_match ON translation (language);
```

I query these tables with this command:

```
Select a.rowid, a.okurigana, a.kana, b.meaning 
from tango a inner join translation b 
   ON a.rowid=b._id AND b.language='eng' 
WHERE a.okurigana MATCH 'A*'"
```

The query takes several seconds to complete. I dont understand why. If I use this query (removed the inner join) the query is extremely fast.

```
Select a.rowid, a.okurigana, a.kana  
from tango a 
WHERE a.okurigana MATCH 'A*';
```

Why does a join kills the performance o.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can speed up the query with the use of indexes.  This is your query:

```
Select a.rowid, a.okurigana, a.kana, b.meaning
from tango a inner join
     translation b
     ON a.rowid = b._id AND b.language = 'eng'
WHERE a.okurigana MATCH 'A*'" ;
```

There are basically two ways for the engine to process this query.  One way is to do the filtering on `tango` using the `where` clause and then to look up the values in `translation`.  For this, a useful index would be:

```
create index translation_id_language_meaning on translation(_id, language, meaning)
```

The other way would be to scan `translation` and then do the the lookup on tango.  For this, a useful index would be:

```
create index translation_language_id_meaning on translation(language, _id, meaning)
```

The first is probably most appropriate for your query, but the better solution depends on the table statistics and distribution of values.

Answer (score 1):

If adding an inner join slows the query down without increasing significantly the number of rows that you get back, it is usually because your schema lacks an index.

In your case, it looks like your `translation._id` or `translation.language` is not indexed (perhaps both columns need indexing).

Adding indexes using the [`CREATE INDEX ...` command](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html) for these two columns should speed up your query.